# Populating custom field set name with a sub-field in layout

Tags: custom-fields, contact-layout-editor

I have a custom field set that allows multiple entires.

They represent "outreaches" for organisations. eg: City Office, Rural outreach office etc.

Each field set has a bunch of information - Outreach name, opening hours, location, desciption etc.

My issue is the following. I have them in a tab on the organisation contact page. When users go into the tab, or edit the content of the tab they see a list of the sub-services but all the entries are named for the parent custom field set. Here is a picture to illustrate the issue:

[image: List of sub-services]

What I want is to populate the heading in the accordion with the value from the "servive name" field of the custom field set.

eg:

[image: expanded sub-set fields]

It's quite frustrating for users at the moment as they must open each service accordion to see which one it actually is when they may only need to update one of them. Most organisation only have 1-3 sub-services but some - as in the above example - have five or more.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

PS - sorry for the image quality. I am having issues with Flameshot screen captures at the moment.

Comment: This would require some costing coding to set the title based on a text field...

Comment: At this point I will settle for any solution that is actually workable for my users so they don't just see a list of meaningless headings. The table solution proposed by @anil below doesn't seem to work and I can't find anyone who knows why. That would also be acceptable.

Comment: what issue are you facing with display in tabs?

Comment: As discussed in my comment below. Setting a field to not show in tables doesn't seem to work. There is no error, the change simply does not take affect. Maybe it is something that can only be done for new fields? I have to change existing fields with data in them.

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to your question but perhaps a solution?

Have you considered changing the custom data set style from Tab to Tab with table?

Tab -
[image: Tab]

Tab with table -
[image: Tab with table]

Comment: There are a lot more fields - some of them large text areas - lower down in each field set. Can the table view be configured to only show 1 or 1 fields?

Comment: Indeed it can, select the Display in Table checkbox for fields that you want displayed.

Help text from CiviCRM on this option - 
Display in Table controls which columns are included in the listing of custom data records. If your custom data set has a large number of fields, uncheck this box to exclude less important fields from the listing. All fields will still be included when viewing a single record. You may also want to exclude Note type fields from the table listing.

Comment: So, when I try to deselect "Display in Table" from a custom field in the field set, it saves without error but the change is not made. Display in table is always selected. No errors appear in the log. Is there some other step to this? Or can it only be done with new fields?

Comment: If anyone could get this solution to actually work, I would accept it also.